# Twilio video - Switching camera not working on android - NotReadableError: could not start a video source

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-video

I am using Twilio with `twilio-video` `v beta-2` counting on the master branch of this [repohttps://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js](http://repohttps://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js) 
I got to display the select media and push the devices into it and the switch is working on ios safari browser, but it's not working on android nasier on chrome browser and firefox browser 
`NotReadableError: could not start a video source` 
my `updateVideoDevice` function is as the following

```
function updateVideoDevice(event) {
const select = event.target
const localParticipant = room.localParticipant
log('change fired ' + select.value);

if (select.value !== '') {
    Video.createLocalVideoTrack({
        audio: true,
        video: {width: 640},
        deviceId: {exact: select.value}
    }).then((localVideoTrack) => {
        const tracks = Array.from(localParticipant.videoTracks.values())
            .map(publication => publication.track);
        localParticipant.unpublishTracks(tracks)
        console.log(localParticipant.identity + " removed track: " + tracks[0].kind)
        tracks.forEach(track => {
            track.detach().forEach(detachedElement => {
                detachedElement.remove()
            })
        })
        localParticipant.publishTrack(localVideoTrack)
        console.log(localParticipant.identity + " added track: " + localVideoTrack.kind)
        const previewContainer = document.getElementById('local-media');

        if (!previewContainer.querySelector('video')) {
            attachParticipantTracks(room.localParticipant, previewContainer)
        }
        // attachTracks([localVideoTrack], previewContainer)
    }).catch((error) => {
        log(error)
    });
}
```

}

Comment: @philnash can you assist hear, please?

Comment: It would be easier to work on this over at GitHub, I'm guessing [this is you too](https://github.com/philnash/mediadevices-camera-selection/issues/1#issuecomment-426986427)?